# Como bloquear botão direito do mouse e Bloquear usuário de visualizar Código Fonte

Tags: javascript

Queria saber se tem como bloquear o clique do botão direito do mouse, com a intensão de esconder meu código fonte, porém se o usuário estiver navegando de um android é só ele digitar `view-source:` e mostrara o código, gostaria de saber como bloquear esse comando também, se é que tem um jeito pra isso

Comment: Você deve fazer uma aplicação segura e não tentar esconder seu código pesquise sobre gulp e grunt alem disso o f12 tbm mostra o código

Comment: Não se preocupe com isso. Com tempo e prática seu código vai ficando limpo e organizado a ponto de você não ter receio de outras pessoas verem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É **impossível** esconder o código-fonte, mesmo desabilitando o botão direito do mouse para cliques na página com:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Basta teclar `CTRL + U` e *Voilà*: código-fonte na tela. Sem contar que alguns navegadores possuem menus ALT com opção para visualizar código-fonte.

*Utilizar este recurso dificulta **um pouquinho** o acesso ao código-fonte a usuários leigos, no entanto, usuários leigos supostamente não estariam interessados em ver seu código-fonte, e mesmo que estivessem, bastaria uma pesquisa simples no Google que achariam com certa facilidade como fazer isso.*

Quanto ao `view-source:`, isso é um recurso do navegador que não pode ser desabilitado via JavaScript (ou qualquer outro script). E nem precisa ser Android: no desktop também funciona.

Comment: e criptografar o código tem como ?

Comment: Tem sim. Um site interessante para criptografar o HTML é esse: http://snapbuilder.com/code_snippet_generator/obfuscate_html_source_code/

Comment: Mas use somente para criptografar o HTML, não use para criptografar scripts. Para criptografar scripts, use outros sites que fazem isso separadamente.

Comment: na verdade eu queria criptografar meu CSS

Comment: Se o CSS não for externo, o site acima funciona. De outra forma, não sei informar.

Answer (score 5):

Enfatizando que todas as duas são praticas ruins, seguem as respostas:

**Sobre Bloquear o comando para ver o Codigo Fonte**

Não é possível impedir que o usuário inspecione o código (view-source:) em execução na máquina. No fim de tudo, o HTML que eles receberão será legível em texto simples. Você pode causar um incômodo para a maioria das pessoas, mas isso não será uma medida de segurança válida - as extensões cromadas ainda serão executadas, por exemplo, então, se alguém estiver usando a extensão NoScript, desativará todos os javascript.

Uma opção muito melhor seria lidar com o seu servidor de lógica, e apenas enviar ao cliente a informação que eles precisam saber / solicitar.

Existem alguns ofuscadores javascript gratuitos, como https://javascriptobfuscator.com/. Lembre-se de que não é um método seguro, no entanto.

**Ja O Click do botão direito pode ser bloqueado**

Como dito pelo Edson

Assim:

```
document.oncontextmenu = document.body.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Não é recomendável porem esta ai ...

```
document.oncontextmenu = document.body.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}
```

Comment: upvote responde uma parte que eu não respondi, vou somar na minha.

Comment: Upvote, você respondeu uma parte que eu não respondi, sobre o bloqueio do click direito. Eu so respondi sobre o bloqueio de ver o html da pagina.

Answer (score -2):

Isso é uma coisa bem simples para se resolver. Apenas digite isso em sua linha de código (`<script/>`):

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

*Observação: isso não é recomendado em seu site.*